# apache redirect to match the number on source and destination

Tags: regex, apache, redirect

source: /abc/xyz/(any digit number).html
dest:   /efg/pqr/(match the number given in source).html

example

```
source: /abc/xyz/748392737383.html
dest:   /efg/pqr/748392737383.html

want a apache redirect to do the above scenario
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this with regex substitutions:

```
RewriteRule ^\/abc\/xyz\/(\d+).html$ /efg/pqr/$1.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/13fnmg/1)